# Update a field in a django model only if it needs updating

Tags: python, mysql, django

Suppose I have some django model and I'm updating an instance

```
def modify_thing(id, new_blah):
    mything = MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    mything.blah = new_blah
    mything.save()
```

My question is, if it happened that it was already the case that `mything.blah == new_blah`, does django somehow know this and not bother to save this [non-]modification again?  Or will it always go into the db (MySQL in my case) and update data?

If I want to avoid an unnecessary write, does it make any sense to do something like:

```
if mything.blah != new_blah:
    mything.blah = new_blah
    mything.save()
```

Given that the record would have to be read from db anyway in order to do the comparison in the first place?  Is there any efficiency to be gained from this sort of construction - and if so, is there a less ugly way of doing that than with the if statement in python?

Comment: You can look at the SQL statements that are being executed, and optimize from there?

Comment: You could override the save method in your models class to check every time the save method id called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/) to ensure that code like that you just posted don´t **write** to the db. Take a look at `pre_save`, that's the signal you're looking for.

Comment: Can you please explain how would this save any DB hits ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that django does not cache the values, a trip to DB is inevitable, you have to fetch it to compare the value. And definitely we have less ugly ways to do that. You could do it as

```
if mything.blah is new_blah:
   #Do nothing
else:
     mything.blah = new_blah
     mything.blah.save()
```

Comment: This code is ok, but I think it fit better into a `pre_save` singal handler. Don't you think?

Comment: Ideally a signal would be used when you want to process something prior or post the mentioned action, eg: prior saving something i might want to check if some conditions are met and exist. Here for the given use case it adds more of complexity than solving the problem.